# Two column with span float image

Tags: floats, multicol

I'd like to have such layout:

[image: layout]

The \section text and float image objects should span two columns, \subsection and plain text should go in two column.

Now I'm using multicol package for this. This is not very good, because I need to manually break text (in multicols environment) to insert floats and sections. As a result, floats position is hardcoded, so to speak.

Are there any robust way to do this? Maybe, there is a specific class for such a layout?

Comment: what is the order of your text blocks? top left, bottom left, top right, bottom right,  or top left top right bottom left bottom right?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle top-left → top-right → [image] → bottom-left → bottom-right. In general, I'd like LaTeX to automatically put the float, where it will suit. But I'd also need a possibility to put float "exactly here".

Comment: You can turn multicol off and on again to achieve that layout.  You don't HAVE to use a float, Just use \captionof{figure} from the caption package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I'm doing that now. But I don't like it, because image appears exactly at place, where I've turned multicol off. So I have to manually find the best place for image (where to break multicol), and it's position is "hardcoded".

Comment: how would latex know to break the page in the middle rather than just putting the spanning float at the bottom? would it not always need some explicit markup?

Comment: The flowfram package will allow you to place the image in a given spot and let the text flow around it.  You will need to know how big the image is first.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, let's say, latex put it at the bottom by default. But I don't know where to break multicol so that image will be exactly at the bottom. And in some cases I need to explicitly specify image position, so it can appears in the middle of the page, e.g. before new subsection.
Maybe, \twocolumn is quite enough for this, I don't know, I'm a beginner. :)

Comment: You would not have to manually break the multicol you can use `begin{figure*}` for 2-col spanning floats at top or bottom of a multicol

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, that may be ok.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Now I have another problem, using multicol and figure* — latex put image on the next page after position in text, where I've put my float object. And I need this image to be on the same page with the text, corresponding to it.

Comment: So you want "LaTeX" to put the figure where you want, but you want "LaTeX" to automatically put the figure where it sees fit. You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: latex 2-col figures always go on to the next page. You can always move it earlier in the source

Comment: @Joseph Yes, I want to put the figure where I want, _if I need this_, and I want latex to automatically put it in other case. :)

OMG, I just simply want smth, that works like `\begin{figure}` in one column text layout, with possibility to use `[H]` option, if I need one!

@DavidCarlisle I see, thanks.